# Javascript opencv (opencv.js) grabcut GC_INIT_WITH_MASK issue example?

Tags: javascript, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to a run grabcut on opencv.js with having the grabcut mode as `GC_INIT_WITH_MASK`. But not getting the results i need. I am getting the same results from that as i got from using the grabcut mode as `GC_INIT_WITH_RECT`.

there isn't any online exmples of calling opencv.js cv.grabcut with having `GC_INIT_WITH_MASK` as the mode.

so,i checked the official opencv documentation which provides a python example.

in that,

```
cv.grabCut(img,mask,None,bgdModel,fgdModel,5,cv.GC_INIT_WITH_MASK)
```

there is `None` (which is the equivalent of null in javascript) as the 3rd parameter which requires a rectangle object,  And it makes sense to not pass a rectangle here when the mode is `INIT_WITH_MASK`.

But when i call cv.grabcut function in javascript using null in that place. it gives an error,

> TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'x' in null

it runs when i pass a rectangle object. but gives the same result as using `GC_INIT_WITH_RECT` mode.

How to run it properly using `INIT_WITH_MASK` mode?

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem and tried to initialize rectangle without any parameters and provide it to the `GrabCut`:

```
 let rect = new cv.Rect();
 cv.grabCut(src, mask, rect, bgdModel, fgdModel, 1, cv.GC_INIT_WITH_MASK);
```

And it works (I can see difference with my own mask). At first, I did not see any difference too, but it reveals that I used the same mask as before with `GC_INIT_WITH_RECT` option.

Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

```
let rect = new cv.Rect(100, 100, 400, 400);
cv.grabCut(src, mask, rect, bgdModel, fgdModel, 1, cv.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).